# Is it possible to get this pin oak to grow straight?

Tags: trees, tree-care, growth, oak

Received a pin oak from my uncle a little less than two years ago as a transplant.  It's about 9ft tall today.  The tree had a noticeable bend to it when when it was transplanted.  I tried staking it, but that appears to have made things worse as the top is growing very crooked.  I've been doing a bit of research online and it seems that staking is a somewhat contentious practice.  I've removed all the staking.

A couple of questions for the community.  I don't mind a little bend, but the current bend at the top is excessive.  Is it likely the tree will straighten up if I leave it alone?  Can I use guy wires to help fix this or will it only make matters worse?

Thanks for any input.

[image: Here's a picture of the pin oak in question]

Comment: http://forums2.gardenweb.com/discussions/1727512/bent-pin-oak-trunk-straighten

Answer (score 4):

If the tree has been planted for over a year you do not need a stake and should remove that t-Bar.
Consider the direction of the prevailing wind.  If the tree is leaning away from that direction you may have a clue.

Also, I notice the large branch midway up heading off in the direction of your house.  Branches do not move up as the tree grows and the thought of a large branch at waist level is uncomfortable.  I recommend cutting the branch off cleanly which will reduce the weight on that side.  Once you have done that does the tree sit straighter?

Splinting, as Paul Nardini suggests, is a viable option but not a set and forget one.  The splint should be removed every year and reset to accommodate the current year's growth

Comment: Thanks for the input.  The t-bar has been removed.  I will be pruning the large branch -- I was afraid to do too much pruning right after the transplant.  I'll be pruning that branch once the colder temps arrive for good.

Answer (score 3):

You can still straighten that tree with a couple splints.

http://hort.ufl.edu/woody/year-two-splint1.shtml  gives an overview. Wrap it, against it's will, tightly to something straight and let it go for a season.